# Diagram Fixed Size with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, symbology, diagram

I try to change the parameters of a diagram using PyQGIS 3 but I can’t find the function in the QgsDiagramSettings class to set it to "Fixed size" (and not "Scale Size) and set a value. Here is my code:

```
    diagram = QgsPieDiagram()
    ds = QgsDiagramSettings()
    dColors = {'"Con_A"': QColor('#33a02c'),'"Con_B"': QColor('#000000')}
    ds.categoryColors = dColors.values()
    ds.categoryAttributes = dColors.keys()
    ds.categoryLabels = ds.categoryAttributes
    ds.sizeType = 0 #0 = Millimeters, 1 = Map Units, 2 = Pixels, 4 = Points, 5 = Inches

    dr = QgsLinearlyInterpolatedDiagramRenderer()
    dr.setLowerValue(0.0)
    dr.setDiagram(diagram)
    dr.setDiagramSettings(ds)
    camembert.setDiagramRenderer(dr)
    
    dls = QgsDiagramLayerSettings()
    dls.setPlacement(1)
    layer.setDiagramLayerSettings(dls)
    
    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Another element, the "dls.setPlacement(1)" seems to be set but not to be applied when running the code. Does anyone know where the problem comes from?